# How to make a border?

Tags: javascript

I have element

```
<div id="square"></div>
```

He has a property to move on document

```
var square = document.getElementById("square");
    document.body.onkeydown = function(e) {
    if (e.keyCode == 37) {left()}
    if (e.keyCode == 38) {up()}
    if (e.keyCode == 39) {right()}
    if (e.keyCode == 40) {down()}
}
```

How I make a function, which not allowed movement, if `square` element is closest to document border?
JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/zutxyLsq/

Comment: So check the position before you move it?

Comment: It's called "Collision Detection", have a Google and learn some things

Comment: @epascarello, so I have that function
`function checkBorder() {
    if (parseInt(getComputedStyle(square)['left'], 10) < 10 || parseInt(getComputedStyle(square)['right'], 10) < 10 || parseInt(getComputedStyle(square)['top'], 10) < 10 || parseInt(getComputedStyle(square)['bottom'], 10) < 10);
} return false`, but
if element is near document border, other move-functions are not worked.

Comment: [Something like this?](https://jsfiddle.net/zutxyLsq/2/)

Comment: @musefan, yeah! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You need to check if left is outside of boundaries like this:

```
function left() {
    console.log('Left');
    var left = parseInt(square.style.left || getComputedStyle(square)['left'], 10);
    if (left >= 50) {
        square.style.left = (left - 50) + 'px';
    }
}
function right() {
    console.log('Right');
    var left = parseInt(square.style.left || getComputedStyle(square)['left'], 10);
    if (left+50+square.offsetWidth < window.innerWidth) {
        square.style.left = (left + 50) + 'px';
    }
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/zutxyLsq/3/

and the same for up and down.